# Can't Parse JSON Date from SQL Server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Im getting a JSON date back from SQL Server that looks like this:

`"/Date(-62135568000000-0800)/"`

when I try to parse the date using:
`var date = new Date(parseInt(MyDate) * 1000);`  I get Invalid Date

ultimately I'm trying to put these dates on an x axis of d3 time series plot.

Is there a way I can use this JSON date value in d3?

EDIT:

I found a work-around on the SQL Server side by returning the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 as an int

Comment: is your `MyDate` variable containing `"/Date(-62135568000000-0800)/"` ? If so, then it wouldn't convert it to date. It should be having only `-62135568000000-0800` i guess so.

Comment: You would need to extract the actual date part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function

```
function GetJSDateFromMS(str)
{
    return eval("new " + str.replace(/\//g,""));
}
```

Pass datetim string varibale to function and it will return you a Javascript datetime object.

```
GetJSDateFromMS("/Date(345345345345)/")
```

`Thu Dec 11 1980 06:45:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`